# CSS Transform z-index bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, transform

So i have made a deck of cards that can be turned around by pressing them. For some reason on iOs the cards ignore the z-index. I have an example here: http://daviddf77.seventyseven.axc.nl/flip/

So lets say the card on top has z-index 99; the card underneath it has a z-index of 98. Why does the transform transition cause the z-index to not apply anymore? It seems that during the transition the z-index gets put to 0. And then when the transition has finished its correct again.

I tried a lot of different things to fix this, like adding a transform-origin, translate3d, z-index transition etc. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: I see no bugs. I think I don't see what you mean.

Comment: Position: absolute, position: relative and translates have priority to z-index.